# To prove that irrational powers of 1 is equal to 1

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, perfect-powers

It is easy to prove that if **1** is raised
to any power of a rational number ( say $x$), then :

$(1)^x = (1)^{p/q}$

(because $x$ can be expressed as $p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers except $q≠0$). And,

$(1)^{(p/q)} = (1)^p/(1)^q = 1/1 = 1$

But I am stuck in proving following :

a)   $1^π = 1$

b)   $1^e = 1$

c)   $1^{\sqrt3} = 1$

Or in general, how to prove $1^{y}$ = 1 , where $y$ is an irrational number.

I would appreciate any help in proving above things .

Comment: Perhaps show $\log(1^x)=0$ for all real $x$ and so $1^x=1$

Comment: Do you know "logarithm "

Comment: What is your definition of real powers?

Comment: @Shiva yes, but how do you define it?

Comment: What does $a^b$ mean when $a>0$ and $b$ is real?  My calculator says $2^\pi \approx 8.825$ but what is it calculating? What is your fundamental definition?

Comment: You can define irrational powers using continuity or monotonicity between rational powers, or using logarithms and antilogarithms, or using something else.  But you need to tell us your definition, and your choice affects how difficult the proof is.

Comment: See [Exponentiation: real exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents): "For positive real numbers, exponentiation to real powers can be defined in two equivalent ways..."

Comment: You have to use definitions: the def for integer exponents, based on "repeated" multiplication, does **not** work for *real* exponents. You have to find a suitable def that - for the case of exponents that are integers - fits with the already available one. This is the way math works...

Comment: How about show that $a^0=1$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0 $. Then use that to establish for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $1^x=(a^0)^x=a^0=1.$

Comment: @Shiva Keep fair. We did not know what you are allowed to use , in this case that the exponential laws hold also for real exponents as long as the base is positive. Strictly speaking , it requires high math to justify those laws.

Comment: @Shiva Forgive my harsh criticism, but your request is, as JMoravitz pointed out, unfair, and hypocritical, not to mention illogical. You said "definitions are off-topic for this question." **No, they are not.** Definitions are at the foundation of all mathematics. There are no mathematics without definitions. You cannot prove any statements without definitions. If you want me to prove "The sky is blue," you first need to give me definitions of the words "sky" and "blue." Otherwise, the sentence is incoherent. I vote this question be closed.

Comment: @BasantaRajPahari That would be an invalid proof, since it is necessarily circular. You cannot assert $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ without proof. To prove it, you need to accept a definition to begin with.

Comment: I am sorry everyone for the dumb things I did in past. I had edited to make it more focused and removed un-necessary things.Also , I accept the definitions of laws of exponents to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand what $1^x$ means when $x$ is irrational. If $x$ is rational, then it can be written as $x=p/q$ in reduced form. Then, for any real number $a$, the definition of $a^x$ is
$$
\sqrt[q]{a^p},
$$
where $a^p=a\cdot a\cdots a$ when $p>0$, and $a^p=(1/a)\cdot (1/a)\cdots (1/a)$ when $p<0$ (both repeated $|p|$ times).

This does not work when $x$ is irrational, so what to we do? The idea is to approximate $x$ by rational numbers. For example, to compute $a^\pi$, you could look at the sequence of numbers
$$
a^3,\;a^{3.1},\;a^{3.14},\;a^{3.141},\dots
$$
Each of these makes sense since any terminating decimal can be written as a fraction. As the exponents get closer and closer to $\pi$, it turns out that the list of numbers will converge to some number. We call the number they converge to $a^{\pi}$. To make all this precise, you need to understand what the limit of a sequence means.

To prove that $1^{\pi}=1$, you just have to note that $1^{\pi}$ is defined as the limit of the sequence $1^{3},1^{3.1},1^{3.14},\dots$, and these numbers are all $1$ because of the rules you stated in your question. Since the limit of a sequence of $1$'s is just $1$, we conclude $1^\pi=1$. The same applies to any irrational number $x$; it is always true that $1^x=1$.

Comment: So, lim(x tends to π) 1^(x) = 1^(π) . I have been taught that limits calculate limiting values and not actual values?

Comment: Hi, I asked for actual values and not limiting values. We can find only limiting values and not actual values because actual values are indeterminable? Thanks